# Outlook crashing after attempting LinkedIn social connector fix - changing ProviderURLLogin registry key

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, linkedin

I've tried the instructions on this [page](http://community.linkedin.com/questions/25083/linkedin-can-not-connected-to-outlook-2013.html?page=30&pageSize=10&sort=votes) where, to get the LinkedIn social connector to work again you make a change to your registry. I made the change and as it did for some, it's now causing my Outlook to crash from time to time.

So I'd like to set this back, but I didn't store the original value anywhere.

Does anyone know where I can find the original value for the following registry key?

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\SocialConnector\SocialProviders\OscAddIn.LinkedInProvider\ProviderURLLogin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it shows as: `https://outlook.linkedinlabs.com/osc/login`

[image]

In the future, I recommend you backup your registry before you make any changes for this very scenario. You can also automate it by using [ERUNT](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/erunt/) - You can set it up in Task Scheduler to run once a day if you wish:

`C:\Windows\Erunt\AUTOBACK.EXE %SystemRoot%\ERDNT\AutoBackup\#Date# sysreg otherusers /noconfirmdelete /noprogresswindow /days:7`

Comment: perfect that looks like the original value. Hopefully it fixes it. And yes, I should have known better. Thanks.